# Get non html content from a page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, regex, vb.net

Is their any possibility to get the non-html content from a page? What i mean by non-html is that, words/sentences in a page other than html tags.

I can take the source code by using

```
Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("SomeWebPage.com")
```

But how can i get the non-html content only from a webpage as like this?

Comment: first, get the value of sourceString in a javascript variable,
Then use jquery with Regex (use a regular expression which can find html tags <>, plenty out there, Google it) to iterate over the html page and get all non-html content

Comment: Good grief!  RegEx?  Try HtmlAgilityPack if you want to parse HTML in the .NET world.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: May be better phrased as you want to extract plain text from an HTML page. To do this use an HTML parser. HTMLAgilityPack is one library this is often used..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if the html is properly structured ...

```
Dim myhtml As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http:\\www.test.com")
Dim plaintext As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(myhtml, "<.*?>", "")
```